# Overriding validation messages FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I overriding validation messages in my Entity.
But when i got errors, the validation messages displayed twice:
First is message from FOSUserBundle(Login is short) and second is my message(Min 6). Why?

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=16,
     *      minMessage="Min 6",
     *      maxMessage="Max 16",
     * )
     */

    protected $username;
    //..

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create own group of validators:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups